# Why this exception occured?

Tags: c#, dictionary

[image]

I have a `dictionary` name `Pair` in c#. It contains some key - value pairs. I added a screen shot, there was an exception generated on `(p.Key == "left)`, `Sequence containes no matching element` but if you see in the `Pair Dictionary`, the `left` key is present there. Then please anybody tell me why this exception occured ?

Comment: What are the types for the key and value (TKey, TValue) of this dictionary?

Comment: Are you sure that you Key is a string?

Comment: Why do you use a Dictionary like an iterator? `Pair["left"]` should be much more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I can see it right, the `left` value is preceded with a whitespace, `" left"`, so `p.Key == "left"` is never true.

Use `p.Key.contains("left")` instead, or check if it returns a value or not, before trying to manipulate it. Or trim the leading and trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx) or [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) instead of [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx). With Single, there is no reason to use dictionary.

Also, your problem stems from the fact, that there is space before the 'left' so the whole string is actually " left". See how width is one character to the left.

Answer (score 1):

If it isnt a white-soace issue, then the only way I can that happening is if the dictionary is a `Dictionary<object,...>`, in which case the `==` you are using is *reference equality*, not *string equality*. That would cause it to fail. If so, either use a `Dictionary<string,...>` or use `Equals("left", p,Key)`.

Note that `Pair["left"]` would be a much better way of doing the lookup.

Comment: == is overriden for strings for string equality.

Comment: @Euphoric: But it's not clear that it is a `Dictionary<string,string>`. It could also be a `Dictionary<object,string>` (where a string is stored as key). In that case Marc is right that reference equality is used not string equality. By the way, someone should not downvote competetitive answers.